# Is there an article with details of table vs css designs for laymen?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to provide a client with a third-party source with some details of why CSS designs are better than table-based ones. We've provided them with details, but they want another source. Most that I've found have been a bit too technical.

Does anyone know of any articles regarding this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one seems pretty good and geared towards the laymen:

http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/index.html